# Mapping composite foreign keys in Grails 2.0.0

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting a org.hibernate.MappingException when trying to map a composite foreign key that has a field that is also part of the primary key in Grails 2.0.0.  Here's what I have:

```
class ClassA {
  static hasMany =[classB: ClassB]

  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['classAId', 'startDate']
    classAId column: 'A_ID'
    startDate column: 'START_DATE'
  }

  Integer classAId
  Date startDate
}

class ClassB {
  static belongsTo = [ClassA]

  static mapping = {
    id composite:['startDate', 'classBId']
    columns {
      startDate: 'START_DATE', insertable: false, updateable: false
      classBId: 'B_ID'
      classA: { // composite FK
        column:'A_ID'
        column:'START_DATE' // adding 'insertable: false, updateable: false' doesn't work here
      } 
    }
  }

  String classBId
  Date startDate
  ClassA classA
}
```

The exception I get is...

...nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ClassB column: START_DATE (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

If I remove the 'startDate' from the composite primary key in ClassB then I don't get the exception.  However, this isn't a solution I can use because I'm dealing with a schema that I cannot change.

Any ideas?

Thanks to the Grails Forum, I have a workaround to this issue.

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Issue-mapping-composite-keys-in-grails-2-0-0-td4397125.html#a4397190